# Printing a Sudoku board in a specific format

Tags: python

I have pasted only parts of the code that I find difficult, otherwise it's an ordinary 9x9 soduko board. It's a nested list

```
    board = [
    [0,0,6,9,0,5,0,1,0],
    [9,7,0,0,1,2,3,0,5],
    [0,2,0,0,0,4,8,6,0],
    [5,0,3,8,0,0,0,2,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,8,0,0,0,1,9,0,7],
    [0,5,4,1,0,0,0,7,0],
    [2,0,7,4,5,0,0,9,3],
    [0,6,0,7,0,3,1,0,0]
]


def formatted_board():
 print(f'{board[0][0:3]} \n {board[1][0:3]} \n {board[2][0:3]}')
 print(board[3][0:3],board[4][0:3],board[5][0:3]) 
 print(board[6][0:3],board[7][0:3],board[8][0:3])
 print(board[0][3:6],board[1][1:6],board[2][1:6])
 print(board[3][3:6],board[4][1:6],board[5][1:6])
 print(board[6][3:6],board[7][1:6],board[8][1:6])
 print(board[0][6:9],board[1][6:9],board[2][6:9])
 print(board[3][6:9],board[4][6:9],board[5][6:9])
 print(board[6][6:9],board[7][6:9],board[8][6:9])


def choose_cell():
 row = int(input("choose row:"))
 column = int(input("choose column:"))
 choose_num = int(input("choose a num between 1 og 9:"))
 if 0< choose_num <=9:
    board[row][column] = choose_num
    formatted_board()
else:
    print("illegal num try again")
    choose_cell()
```

`formatted_board()` goes into `choose_cell()`. The first line in `formatted_board()` prints okay, but I want to print it in the below format every time someone inserts a code:

```
    0 1 2   3 4 5   6 7 8 
  +-------+-------+-------+
0 | 0 0 6 | 9 0 5 | 0 1 0 |
1 | 9 7 0 | 0 1 2 | 3 0 5 |
2 | 0 2 0 | 0 0 4 | 8 6 0 |
  +-------+-------+-------+
3 | 5 0 3 | 8 0 0 | 0 2 0 |
4 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 |
5 | 0 8 0 | 0 0 1 | 9 0 7 |
  +-------+-------+-------+
6 | 0 5 4 | 1 0 0 | 0 7 0 |
7 | 2 0 7 | 4 5 0 | 0 9 3 |
8 | 0 6 0 | 7 0 3 | 1 0 0 |
  +-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: how did you come up with the indices to use in formatted_board()? they are all over the place....

Comment: @pygri , the first line : print(f'{board[0][0:3]} \n {board[1][0:3]} \n {board[2][0:3]}') is the first 3x3 square in the upper left,  the numbers 0,0,6,9,7,0,0,2,0.

Comment: so, capitalizing on the success of printing the first line correctly, try again printing the second line...

Answer (score 1):

How about this print function:

```
def niceSudo(board):
    side    = len(board)
    base    = int(side**0.5)
    def expandLine(line):
        return line[0]+line[5:9].join([line[1:5]*(base-1)]*base)+line[9:]
    line0  = "  "+expandLine("╔═══╤═══╦═══╗")
    line1  = "# "+expandLine("║ . │ . ║ . ║ #")
    line2  = "  "+expandLine("╟───┼───╫───╢")
    line3  = "  "+expandLine("╠═══╪═══╬═══╣")
    line4  = "  "+expandLine("╚═══╧═══╩═══╝")

    symbol = " 123456789" if base <= 3 else " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    nums   = [ [""]+[f"({symbol[-n]})" if n<0 else f" {symbol[n]} "  for n in row]
               for row in board ]
    coord  = "   "+"".join(f" {s}  " for s in symbol[1:side+1])
    lines  = []
    lines.append(coord)
    lines.append(line0)
    for r in range(1,side+1):
        line1n = line1.replace("#",str(symbol[r]))
        lines.append( "".join(n+s for n,s in zip(nums[r-1],line1n.split(" . "))) )
        lines.append([line2,line3,line4][(r%side==0)+(r%base==0)])
    lines.append(coord)
    print(*lines,sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
test =  [ [8,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,3, 6,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,7,0, 0,9,0, 2,0,0],    
          [0,5,0, 0,0,7, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 0,4,5, 6,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,3,0],    
          [0,0,1, 0,0,0, 0,6,8],
          [0,0,8, 5,0,0, 0,1,0],
          [0,9,0, 0,0,0, 4,0,0] ]

niceSudo(test)

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
  ╔═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╗
1 ║ 8 │   │   ║   │   │   ║   │   │   ║ 1
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
2 ║   │   │ 3 ║ 6 │   │   ║   │   │   ║ 2
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
3 ║   │ 7 │   ║   │ 9 │   ║ 2 │   │   ║ 3
  ╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣
4 ║   │ 5 │   ║   │   │ 7 ║   │   │   ║ 4
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
5 ║   │   │   ║   │ 4 │ 5 ║ 6 │   │   ║ 5
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
6 ║   │   │   ║ 1 │   │   ║   │ 3 │   ║ 6
  ╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣
7 ║   │   │ 1 ║   │   │   ║   │ 6 │ 8 ║ 7
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
8 ║   │   │ 8 ║ 5 │   │   ║   │ 1 │   ║ 8
  ╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢
9 ║   │ 9 │   ║   │   │   ║ 4 │   │   ║ 9
  ╚═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╝
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

*The function is good for sudoku sizes up to 36x36 and uses the numbers (or symbols) as coordinates. For pre-set positions, you can give it negative numbers and it will print the symbols between parentheses to indicate that these positions cannot be changed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781746/5237560) for more info on playing and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581709/5237560) for a function to generate a random puzzle.*

Answer (score 0):

```
board = [
    [0,0,6,9,0,5,0,1,0],
    [9,7,0,0,1,2,3,0,5],
    [0,2,0,0,0,4,8,6,0],
    [5,0,3,8,0,0,0,2,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,8,0,0,0,1,9,0,7],
    [0,5,4,1,0,0,0,7,0],
    [2,0,7,4,5,0,0,9,3],
    [0,6,0,7,0,3,1,0,0]
]

def print_board(board):
    print("     0 1 2   3 4 5   6 7 8")
    print("   +-------+-------+-------+")
    for i, line in enumerate(board):
        print(f" {i} |", end="")
        for j, cell in enumerate(line):
            print(f" {cell}", end="")
            if (j+1) % 3 == 0:
                print(f" |", end="")
        print(f"\n", end="")
        if (i+1) % 3 == 0:
            print(f"   +-------+-------+-------+")
```

output :

```
     0 1 2   3 4 5   6 7 8
   +-------+-------+-------+
 0 | 0 0 6 | 9 0 5 | 0 1 0 |
 1 | 9 7 0 | 0 1 2 | 3 0 5 |
 2 | 0 2 0 | 0 0 4 | 8 6 0 |
   +-------+-------+-------+
 3 | 5 0 3 | 8 0 0 | 0 2 0 |
 4 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 |
 5 | 0 8 0 | 0 0 1 | 9 0 7 |
   +-------+-------+-------+
 6 | 0 5 4 | 1 0 0 | 0 7 0 |
 7 | 2 0 7 | 4 5 0 | 0 9 3 |
 8 | 0 6 0 | 7 0 3 | 1 0 0 |
   +-------+-------+-------+
```